# How to make the mouse wrap from corners when moving between monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have 2 monitors. The main one is horizontal, the secondary one is vertical.

[image]

When moving from the right to the left monitor, if the mouse hits the areas I've shown in red, it gets stuck. I would like to change this behavior.

Whenever the mouse hits *any part* of the tall monitor's left edge, it should be wrapped to the wide monitor's right edge. I don't particularly care *where* on the edge it gets wrapped: It's fine if it's just the closest point like I've shown in the image (dashed line is the wrap/teleport).

How can I do this?

Comment: Good use of images, easy to read question +1

Answer (score 5):

Since there was not a "free" answer to this question, I developed a little Windows C# command-line application to deal with this problem, and allow the mouse to move smoothly across multiple monitors, and also to wrap-around between left-most and right-most monitors.

- [MouseUnSnag - GitHub](https://github.com/dale-roberts/MouseUnSnag) - You can compile it from source, or there is an executable provided as a GitHub "release".

**MouseUnSnag** also addresses the "sticky corners" problem, asked in this related superuser post:

- [How to disable sticky corners in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10)

Comment: i recommend using this fork: https://github.com/GrantMoyer/MouseUnSnag

Comment: current development is happening at https://github.com/MouseUnSnag/MouseUnSnag

Answer (score 4):

With Windows display properties this is not possible.

It is made to 'fit' your monitor layout so within display properties you can drag the monitors up and down, etc so that it feels natural to your setup.

For example if the bottom monitor of your left monitor is in line with the bottom of the right monitor then you should drag it down in windows to reflect this, etc.

Not much of an answer but unless a third party can do this Windows cannot.

Answer (score 3):

[DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) has an option on the Settings > Window Management tab, called "Prevent mouse cursor from snagging on unaligned monitor edges" that fixes this issue up.

Disclosure: I do support and testing at Binary Fortress Software (makers of DisplayFusion) :)

Comment: I will add for future readers that while DisplayFusion has a free version, you have to buy it for $30 to get this particular feature.

Comment: Yep, good point. That is one of the features that's only available in the Pro version. I will be sure to mention that in the future.

Comment: It's $30 for a lifetime license. Sounds like a steal to me... I am not affiliated with DisplayFusion at all. I am just a happy customer.

Answer (score 2):

[Continuous Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425) is another simple alternative. It allows you to define exactly the transitions between monitors.

I designed this software with efficiency and having multiple monitors in mind.

[image: Example of an advanced mouse transition configuration]

Comment: Many thanks for mentioning your program in this answer. Monitor 6 in [my setup](https://i.imgur.com/X63dv6Q.png) may swing around, to the left of monitor 3 or below monitor 2/3. The cone-style config is both versatile and intuitive to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 displays (17", 22", 28") each with different screen resolution and I had the same mouse movement issue.
I've tried some tools, but didn't help in my scenario, and DisplayFusion was not free :D, so I've decided to write a script with Autohotkey to solve it.

[Check this script](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=65644#p282017). You can compile it to exe with ahk2exe and later ad it to start-up

This is my scenario:

[image: This is my scenario]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse). Click the "Size" button at the top and adjust the inner height of one monitors to match the other:

[image]