# How to disable sticky corners in Windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-10

It seems Microsoft has tried to solve this problem [Multi-monitors and the corners of the screen](https://superuser.com/questions/136350/multi-monitors-and-the-corners-of-the-screen).

In Windows 7, there is no boundary between monitors and the mouse can move freely across the top of the screen between my 3 monitors, provided I had set their heights equal in display settings. Windows 8 introduced sticky corners. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8).

Windows 10 got sticky corners as well. There are a few pixels at the top corners of each display where the mouse cannot cross over onto the other display. One must move the cursor down to avoid this region in order to get to the next display.

The image shows roughly the region where mouse movement is not permitted in Windows 10, but is allowed in Windows 7.

[image]

Personally, I had no problem with unrestricted mouse movement across the top of my screens - I got used to "aiming" for the x, and the convenience of unrestricted cursor movement. Like all the people who wanted to disable it in W8, I'm wondering if there is a way to disable it in W10.

**Edit to address possible duplicate:**

Although the problem is identical to the one in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8), solutions to solve the problem in W8 involving editing the registry key `MouseCornerClipLength` do not work in W10, since that registry key is not present in W10. Also adding that key and setting the value doesn't work. I searched the entire registry and couldn't find it in another location. No other W10 keys in the node referenced in the W8 solution are obvious replacements.

**Edit to address possible solutions in comments**

harrymc's [suggestion 1](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hot-corners-charms-bar-and-app-switch-list-in-windows-8-1/) and [suggestion 2](http://www.howtogeek.com/127645/how-to-disable-the-charms-bar-and-switcher-hot-corners-in-windows-8/) that worked for for Windows 8.1 do not work in Windows 10.

Comment: No idea, but I think I'll like that feature :)  [Fitts's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law)  Apparently Apple changed their "close window" widget from extending to the edge of the display to a smaller circle, and the "perceived size" of that went from a nearly infinitely sized target to a teeny-tiny target. This feature makes the target bigger!

Comment: This has not just to do with the close window button, but other things. For instance, moving a window from one display to the next. You used to be able to drag the display directly across the top of the display into the other one. Now you must move it down while dragging then move it back up. I was crashing into boundaries all last night after installing W10. I can't believe more people haven't complained :)

Comment: Just a note but you might try adding those keys where they were in 8. Sometimes keys will still work but are not present in the first place. Make sure it is the same type and capitalization. (Note. Be careful doing this. Any registry adjustment is at your own risk. Blah blah blah.)

Comment: @birdman3131 It doesn't work, well didn't in the beta http://superuser.com/questions/935912/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10

Comment: I was not sure hence why i added it as a comment rather than an answer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Do these solution from W8.1 work in W10 : [link1](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hot-corners-charms-bar-and-app-switch-list-in-windows-8-1/) and [link2](http://www.howtogeek.com/127645/how-to-disable-the-charms-bar-and-switcher-hot-corners-in-windows-8/) ?

Comment: @harrymc neither solution works in W10. Thanks though

Comment: W10 is too new. It might take some time until a solution is found.

Comment: @harrymc despite a long and widely participated in beta

Comment: The hackers will only get interested when the user-base is large enough.

Comment: I just want to cry whenever I accidentally close an application by accident thinking that some programmer at Microsoft spent time implementing this stupid feature and did not think one second that people would click on the X button when all they wanted to do was giving the focus to a window on the other screen. Design books will talk about this one in the future

Comment: @djv: You can use Win+Shift+Arrows to move apps from one display to the other. It's much faster than dragging them. *Sticky Corners* still very much suck, though.

Comment: It's still a problem in 2023. There is an open [problem report](https://aka.ms/AAjhebg) in the Feedback-Hub, but think it needs more upvotes to be noticed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 43):

The thread
[How to disable sticky corners in Windows 10?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_personal/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10/cb077f2d-920f-4f51-8e61-28578ab31ec9)
from answers.microsoft.com treats this same problem :

> When moving the mouse from the left monitor to to the top left of the
> right monitor the 6 pixel corner will catch your mouse.
>
> I have similar problem in windows 8.1 and changing
> MouseCornerClipLength in registry to 0 from 6 and disable Corner
> Navigation in Taskbar and Start menu properties helped.
>
> Anyway in Win10 i can't find MouseCornerClipLength, Corner Navigation
> disabled at all and adding same registry keys won't help.

The answer on June 4, 2015, by a Microsoft Support Engineer named Vijay B was :

> We are aware of this issue and it is currently being investigated.
> Stay tuned and we will update this thread when additional information
> becomes available.
>
> If any other posters experiencing this have not submitted this through
> the Windows Feedback App, please do so. This article
> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_apps-insider_feedback/how-to-share-feedback-on-windows-10-technical/5e501781-a580-43e3-8926-40ae19343805 explains using the Windows Feedback App.

It seems that your only option is currently to wait for a future improvement,
or for some hacker to come up with the right hack.
Adding your voice to the [Windows Feedback App](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/category/93584-windows-feedback-app) might help.

[**EDIT1**] The open-source application [Non Stick Mouse](http://www.jawfin.net/?page_id=143) is said to offer
a solution in the case of multiple monitors.
The developer states:

> What it does is hop the mouse over the sticking corners, as well as
> the screen edges when moving windows. Thus it allows the dragging of
> windows through screens without your mouse getting hijacked by the
> Snap Assist.
>
> [...]
> This application does not read or write to any drive, it does not
> access the registry or connect to the Internet.

Warning: It has been noted in the comments that
virustotal finds malware in the latest version of "non stick mouse".

[**EDIT2**]

I have found a
[source](https://appuals.com/disable-sticky-corners-edges-in-windows-10/)
that gives a solution for Windows 10 (which I'm unable to test now):

1. **Disable Snap**
   In *Settings > System > Multitasking*, set Snap to Off.
2. **Registry modification**
   Create and execute the following `.reg` file:

   ```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
    "MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=dword:00000001

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI]
    "MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=-
   ```

[**EDIT3**] Microsoft might have finally disabled this in its
latest versions.

Comment: Nearly three months later. Just updated to Windows 10 and this is still an issue. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of where to complain.

Comment: Is this still an issue? No settings for this implemented yet?

Comment: As of writing this, this is still an issue.

Comment: Please, if you give feedback in the Feedback App, either simply vote for whichever one of the many existing posts has the most votes instead of (or at least in addition to) creating another post.  Or add a new post and upvote All of the existing posts (which is what I did).  I don't see any other way to resolve the issue than to sufficiently raise awareness.

Comment: Still an issue in 2017

Comment: multiple detections in virustotal for the latest "non stick mouse". https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/4f9f99121284f7d36102d5001075ece7c0989ccb99d5dfc783c1515edcaf1b6c/detection

Comment: @Neuralrank: Thanks, I have added a warning.

Comment: How does it take 3 years to fix such a simple issue? It's 2018 and still nothing.

Comment: @harrymc The utility's creator posted the source code on Github, so people can see it's not a virus. Unfortunately, that doesn't stop AVs from quarantining it.

Comment: @mbomb007: Usually one can add an exception to the antivirus.

Comment: @harrymc Not if you're at work. Then someone else manages that.

Comment: Still an issue at the end of 2018, they'll never fix it.

Comment: The year is 2019, still no improvement.

Comment: Microsoft often improves their software HAHAHAHA I'm kidding, anyone who used the windows 98 display properties box that does not fit on the screen knows that what you see in version 1.0 is what you get until end-of-life

Comment: 2020 checking in, still no fix

Comment: Also checking in, 2020. Latest company laptop "refresh" moves me from 7 to 10, and this horrible productivity-dinging "feature" is apparently STILL unfixable. (And for any type of security-conscious company's laptops, you can forget about any "homegrown" solution.)

Comment: @JeffY: See if my second Edit above helps in any way.

Comment: No, sorry, that didn't help. :-( I rebooted after the suggested reg changes as the link says. Several tries with different configs based on the link and your reg code (hand implemented).

Comment: I've tried the reg-fix and Non-stick-mouse.  I found that NSM didn't work so well - if I put my PC to sleep, the task would get stuck somehow and the sticky would return ... I've always hated sticky things! The registry hack seems to work for me, however, I didn't have the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI` key on my PC, so that may be worth investigating.

Comment: Hello 2021, sticky corners still a thing...

Comment: -1 because it didn't work and the up-vote score is very misleading. Dale's MouseUnSnag solution works nicely.

Comment: Appreciate the effort here, I downvoted because the registry solution did not work for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Downvoting in 2021 a very useful answer from 2015 because it doesn't work any more is pointless. There are many old answers here that don't work any more, no point in downvoting them all. I believe that a comment in such a case is enough.

Comment: The tiny app `MouseUnSnag` works perfectly now in Windows 10. It was written in C# [originally by dale below](https://superuser.com/a/1364254/138611) and now lives at https://github.com/MouseUnSnag/MouseUnSnag. I'd recommend folks give it a shot!

Comment: 2023. Problem is still going on. We need a little of patient to finish a whole decade of Windows ignoring the hell out of us <3

Answer (score 29):

I developed an application to deal with this issue as Microsoft evidently seem intent to ignore it.  You can get it from here: http://www.jawfin.net/nsm

Comment: Yay, someone noticed!  But staying on-topic, if anyone needs help with this app, or has suggestions for improvement please post on my site so all can see it in one place. Cheers :)

Comment: This works surprisingly well, although it has trouble crossing monitors with different resolutions.

Comment: @JonathanBarton Your application shows up as a virus in [scans](https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10#comment1816927_951334). Is there a reason why? It shows as suspicious when scanned by MBAM as well.

Comment: Hi @mbomb007 - there are copious comments on the related website here http://jawfin.net/nsm detailing all the fun I've had with AVs. Please read those for more information and ways you can satisfy yourself the application is clean. Cheers

Comment: @JonathanBarton Thanks, I hadn't checked the comments.

Comment: @mbomb007 This app works by constantly tracking the mouse from a hidden window, which probably makes it look like spyware to security software heuristics.  (Not to say that any given executable is necessarily clean, just it makes sense that it would set off anti-virus warnings either way.)

Comment: This application is absolutely awesome! Thank you! PS: In case the website goes down for whatever reason, you can find the source-code at https://github.com/Jawfin/nsm.

Answer (score 14):

In the spirit of Jonathan Barton's contribution above, I developed a little Windows C# command-line application to deal with this problem, and allow the mouse to move smoothly across multiple monitors, and also to *wrap-around between left-most and right-most monitors*. Note that this program does not require a "heuristic" to determine when the cursor is near the screen edge, so the cursor flows very smoothly across the edges.

- [MouseUnSnag - GitHub](https://github.com/dale-roberts/MouseUnSnag) - You can compile it from source, or there is an executable provided as a GitHub "release".

**MouseUnSnag** also addresses this related **superuser.com** question about the cursor getting stuck on edges of monitors of differing heights:

- [How to make the mouse wrap from corners when moving between monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/865469/how-to-make-the-mouse-wrap-from-corners-when-moving-between-monitors)

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic tool. It's a pleasure to use. Even better than it sounds, in practice.

Comment: This works for me but Chrome detects it as a virus when downloading. I'm only using built-in Windows AV so not sure if Chrome just delegates to that. However, on its readme there are instructions on how to compile and they worked perfectly. I didn't realize how easy nuget is and how small the C# compiler is. Didn't see anything "funny" in the source file so feel good about the AV issue. However, to use permanently, need to have it run not from CLI I think.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on getting flagged by AV. It may be because the EXE is "unsigned", so it might show up as "unknown publisher" or something similar.

Comment: This works beautifully! Better than my script (answer above). Also: For the incredibly lazy/dumb (like me) here's a link to the releases page to download: https://github.com/dale-roberts/MouseUnSnag/releases -- p.s. Can you update this to not include the console when you launch it?

Comment: p.s. In the meantime, I'll launch this on startup and just minify it to the system tray using [RBTray](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray) (I also submitted [a request](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray/issues/20) there to allow a command line option to minify regular apps on startup, too)

Comment: I just ran this on windows 11 and it works perfectly. Thanks! The sticky corners drive me mad!

Answer (score 6):

**Partial solution**

- Disable "Snap"
- Doesn't fix the whole problem, but makes it a lot less severe.
- Easy to do: Disable "Snap" in Windows 10.  See below for details.
- You can implement the workaround for a full solution if you really want to, but it's a lot of work since you'd literally need to make a program to do it.  Details at the end of this post.

**Background**

I have a 6-monitor set up:

```
                Monitors
   Top row:  [#1] [#2] [#3]
Bottom row:  [#4] [#5] [#6]   (eye-level; #5 is main display)
```

Whenever I moved a window from one monitor to another, Windows 10 would check to see if I wanted to maximize it.  This features, called "Snap", appears to be bugged because it frequently prevented me from moving a window from one display to another.  I found this SuperUser question while frustrated about it.

Disabling Snap really helped me.  This also automatically disabled [Aero shake](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/minimize-windows-on-the-desktop-using-shake), which I consider to be a bonus.

**Procedure**

To disable "Snap" and "Aero shake":

1. Go to:

   - "Control Panel"
   - --> "All Control Panel Items"
   - --> "Ease of Access Center"
   - --> "Make the mouse easier to use".
2. Check "Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen".
3. Click "OK" or "Apply".

**Results**

- "Snap", which blocked moving windows from one screen to another, is now disabled.  Windows can move freely.
- "Aero shake", which causes all windows to minimize when one window is shaken, is now disabled.
- "Sticky corners", which causes a similar problem but at just the corners (and not all boundaries), is still a problem.  As best as I can tell, there is currently (2015-08-18) no way to disable Sticky Corners or further mitigate the problems it causes.

**Workaround**

There's a workaround for Sticky Corners, but it's not fun.  The gist is that you make a WPF program that puts small black squares at the corner of each of your displays, then when the program detects mouse movement over those squares, it hops your mouse to the next screen as intended.  Technically you'd probably want to adjust the shape of the "squares" to match whatever area Sticky Corners actually affects (probably an L-like shape?).

Basically:

1. Download Visual Studio, e.g. Visual Studio 2015 Community.
2. Make a WPF project.
3. Have the WPF application make a `Window` on every page.  For each `Window`:

   ```cs
   this.Topmost = true;
   this.AllowsTransparency = true;
   this.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
   this.WindowState = WindowStates.Maximized;
   Border border = new Border();
   this.Content = border;
   border.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
   border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
   border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
   border.MouseMove += HandleThisByMovingTheMouseToTheCorrectScreen();
   ```
4. Write `HandleThisByMovingTheMouseToTheCorrectScreen()` to move the mouse to the appropriate location, thus avoiding Sticky Corners from trapping it.
5. If you want to get fancy, instead of a `Border`, make a `Grid` with a separate `Canvas` for each corner (as opposed to the `Border`, which would also cover the edges that aren't corners on each screen).

Comment: What does this have to do with what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @Verdolino:  It significantly relieved the problem that caused me to find this question, so I thought that it might help others in my position.  I added a **Workaround** section detailing how to make a WPF program that'd fix the Sticky Corners issue, if you'd like to go that far.  But it'd probably take an hour or two to write it.

Comment: If it solves the problem. But you even said *"Sticky corners", which causes a similar problem but at just the corners (and not all boundaries), is still a problem*.

Comment: The "solution" I provided disables a "Sticky Edges"-like bug that I seemed to be encountering on Windows 10 Education x64.  This problem affected all edges instead of just the corners.  Once implemented, that problem goes away, but the more limited "Sticky Corners" problem remains.  The work around program fixes the Sticky Corners problem by literally detecting whenever your mouse gets trapped by Sticky Corners and moving it programmatically to the next screen.

Comment: Just to note it, I'm calling the second part a "workaround" since we really shouldn't have to write programs to overcome the Sticky Corners bug.  Ideally Microsoft would get their game together and fix it for us.  But, if you really, *really* hate the bug enough to sink a few hours into writing the program, it'd solve the problem.  I guess you could recover the value of the time lost by instead writing the fix as a UWP (instead of WPF) and putting it up on the Windows Store.

Comment: I actually did write a program for this.  Extremely Quick & Dirty, I even hard-coded my corner points - but it could be friendly if desired!  I am only posting though to note the workaround above needs more work that the answer provides. If you just move the mouse to the next corner of the adjacent monitor the sticky corner picks that up too - you have to move it into the current monitor away from the corner (8 pixels does it) - then move it onto the next monitor. You also have to sleep the UI thread to stop Win10 re-grabbing it even after that -.-

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an option in Windows 10, which is the subject of this question, perhaps only in Windows 8?

Comment: @PProteus It's in Windows 10.  I dunno if it's also in Windows 8, but that does seem plausible.  Did you have trouble finding something described in the above?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit on December 19, 2021:** I'm now using the C# based app `MouseUnSnag` written by dale ([shared above](https://superuser.com/a/1364254/138611)) and is now living here: https://github.com/MouseUnSnag/MouseUnSnag

It now features a system tray icon where you can enable/disable various features, including disabling sticky corners and preventing the mouse from getting stuck in the corners between monitors of varying resolutions.

[image: MouseUnsnag Screenshot]

*Original answer below.*

---

This also bugged me. I've taken a crack at implementing a solution in [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) which retains all the main "snap" features while allowing you to disable strictly the "sticking" of your mouse that happens in the corners between monitors.

**Workaround:**

https://github.com/patricknelson/win10-sticky-mouse

1. Install [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)
2. Download and run [win10-sticky-mouse.ahk](https://github.com/patricknelson/win10-sticky-mouse/raw/master/win10-sticky-mouse.ahk) from the above repo.

The key here is to watch messages from `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and use that to predict where the mouse will be going, then hopping over (cross axis to the primary axis of movement) just enough to ensure Windows doesn't [un]helpfully catch your mouse.

If you're still having issues, please try giving this a shot and let me know if that helps. Any issues or pull requests are very welcome!

Comment: This works and isn't flagged as a virus by as many AVs. [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/692ae1bb5d6be8187f73cbef4654d6531376ec5baf96e2e7afabf04a153a7d73/detection)

Comment: You can use the `exe` but I'd still recommend downloading AutoHotkey and loading the `ahk` script directly (just double clicking); just a safer habit as a general rule of thumb.

Comment: I'm actually now using MouseUnSnag, originally written by dan above and now maintained at https://github.com/MouseUnSnag/MouseUnSnag. I've edited my answer above to reflect this change and it seems to work beautifully for OP's original issue. It is visible in the system tray and includes the option to enable/disable various features. Updates should be coming soon which include the ability to persist options as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this has always been an option of if it has recently just been implemented but I found the solution by Going into
**Settings > System > Multitasking

Then Shut Off Snap By Shutting off "Arrange Windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or conveners of the screen"**
which will shut off all the Snap Settings
I found this setting from a tutorial on this site: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-disable-snap-assist-windows-10/

Visual walk through:

**Open Settings and Click on System**

[image: Open Settings and Click on System]

**Click on Multitasking and Shut off The First Snap Option**

[image: Click on Multitasking and Shut off The First Snap Option]

Comment: The question is about corners where the mouse gets stuck, your answers is about arrange windows

Comment: What? I posted this answer almost a year before it was just added to the top answer. So, yes, this is about the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the application [Display Fusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/).  It takes care of the problem even in Windows 10.  The setting you are looking for is under settings:Mouse Management: Prevent mouse cursor from sticking in Sticky Corners (Windows 10).

Comment: Where can we get this software?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Found it: http://www.displayfusion.com/. As of now, it costs $35 for a household license, but does appear to solve the problem.

Comment: Tried this with DisplayFusion latest and it still does not fix the corner snag when the monitors are all the same resolution.

Comment: @xofz I've been using DisplayFusion for years, though never the Mouse Management functions. I tested it for experimental sake, and it appears to work just fine with my two identical monitors side-by-side. If you've got a different orientation where it doesn't work, you might consider letting the Binary Fortress folks know. The poster did cite the wrong function, though. I've submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be present in Windows 10 when there is *a gap* between two displays in the 'Select and rearrange displays' config section. I was able to fix the issue by slightly moving the two displays towards each other so there is visually no gap between them.

[image: Display Arrangement with gap]

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. This exact same thing happened to me after rewiring my monitors, which required rearrangement of my monitors in Windows. After this rearrangement (I have 4 monitors, 2x2) I noticed that my mouse would stick between just two monitors. I realigned the monitor layout in Windows and then the problem went away.

Comment: Same here. Just fixed my issue, which appeared out of nowhere. Was driving me crazy. Turns out I accidentally moved my upper monitor (I also have a 2h + 1v monitor setup) too far.

If you stick them close enough, the "invisible wall" is gone (Windows 10).
This answer should have more upvotes

Answer (score -1):

This was a Windows 8 feature called sticky corners (IIRC). [Here's someone who claims to have disabled it with a registry change:](https://superusersome.wordpress.com/2015/05/23/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8/)

1. In registry, search: MouseCornerClipLength
2. Set the value to 0 (from 6)
3. Repeat (there is more than one key with this name, I’m not sure which one(s) are necessary)
4. Restart

Note that I'm not currently in a situation to try this out, so let me know if this doesn't solve your problem and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: I'm similarly not in that situation atm, but I will try it first thing when I get home. Thanks

Comment: Looked promising but it doesn't work in Windows 10. See my edit.

Comment: This answer looks like it belongs to this question that is the same one but for Win 8: http://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this will help others. But, I simply dragged the monitor numbers to move #1 to where #2 was and vice versa. It worked. And, so far (fingers crossed) it has not reverted to the mouse sticking problem. Good luck.

Comment: But then the monitors would be the wrong way around...?

Answer (score -2):

Temporary fix.  I returned to my Logitech wireless mouse.  I'd been using a Minicute left hand mouse, but it gets stuck.  So far, the Logitech M705 mouse does not. Logitech must have seen it coming.