# Disable windows 10 invisible border grid function

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10

I have no idea what this new "function" is called, but in windows 10, when you have multiple monitors set up, the adjacent border of the two monitors acts like a border. So when you drag a window at normal speed to the adjacent border, instead of moving the window to the other monitor, W10 acts as if there is only one monitor and that adjacent border is the end border and expand the window I'm dragging to take half of the current monitor screen. To moving a window from one monitor to another, I apparently have to drag it very fast across the adjacent border, otherwise windows would think I want half-maximize the window.

How can I disable this and return how it was on Windows 7?

Comment: If you keep going past the edge, it should move, I think. Unless this is different and you need to do it in task view.

Comment: No I want to remove it that "function" complete. If I want to half-maximize it (sorry, I don't know the jargon for it), I can just use Windows Key + an arrow key.

Comment: I think it's called "Snap" - that might help you searching for a solution.

Comment: A similiar question I answered : [http://superuser.com/questions/949749](http://superuser.com/questions/949749)... Just go faster. Higher your mouse cursor speed ? If you disable Aero Snap, it wiil disable maximizing your windows too.

Comment: That question is pending on [Microsoft's Windows 10 Forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/neep-help-to-disable-aero-snap-between-monitors/c55bb627-9d5b-4751-97cc-812fd1c69059)

Answer (score 1):

To turn Snap on or off:

[image]

In *Ease of Access Center* you can find this setting under *Make the mouse easier to use*:

**Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to edge of the screen.**

Comment: I had to remove the correct answer status because after I ticked "prevent windows from ..." box, all borders are disabled, I just want to return Windows 10 to what it was like in windows 7, ignore the border between the two monitors, not the real boundary borders.

Comment: ps. it made it much worse, because it also disabled Windows key + arrow key function too.

Comment: Well, the choice given by the Microsoft is binary. You have to pick one. If you want custom  option you will likely have to use some third party tool or dive deep in registry changes (without guarantees it will work as intended).
As a side note i think you can use display port splitter and connect two monitors to one display port. Your computer will then see them as one big display hence you will have no middle border.

Comment: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/laptop/connect-two-displays-one-displayport-3512136/