# Adjust window snap speed on multi-monitor setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, aero-snap

I am using a multi-monitor setup and every time I try to move a window from one monitor to the other it tries to snap it on the side of the current monitor not letting me move it over to the other monitor.

The only way to prevent that is by moving the window really fast. Is there a way to adjust the movement speed threshold so it only snaps if I move it really slow to the border of the monitor?

Comment: They do not have the exact same resolution and they are aligned according to where they are. The setup is fine and it's for sure not a user error. You can even turn that snapping of in the win 10 settings, but that is not what I am looking for. I am pretty sure there is a regedit entry that defines the speed threshold. I am just looking for one who know where to find it.

Comment: Related: [Why am I blocked from dragging windows across screen boundaries (multiple monitors) in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/949749/why-am-i-blocked-from-dragging-windows-across-screen-boundaries-multiple-monito)

Comment: He understands why it's blocked, he just want to lower the speed theshold. If you find a way to do so, please post it here!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the register values are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. I couldn't find one for speed but when you drag the window over and it snaps, just keep dragging it and it will continue on it's way. Not sure if that's a new feature since when you first posted this or not.