# How to drag windows between screens more slowly?

Tags: windows-10

As a followup question to [Why am I blocked from dragging windows across screen boundaries (multiple monitors) in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/949749/218306) which describes the bug (feature?) in windows 10 where you must move your cursor very fast to drag windows between screens.

Can I reduce the speed required to drag windows between screens without them getting stuck on the boundaries?

Comment: Its not really a bug.  It does not appear that this setting is configurable at this time in the current or current preview build of Windows 10.  You can disable the need to drag the window quickly to avoid snapping the explorer window, if your willing to forgo, the Snap feature itself.

Comment: Right it can be disabled, but that is not my question, I want to adjust the speed required to allow a free drag between monitors @Ramhound

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I provided my response to that question, there is no way to configured the speed of the cursor required to avoid the Snap feature.  You can either disable it and use any speed you want, or enable it, and move the cursor faster the the required speed to avoid snap feature.