# Moving windows between monitors makes mouse go stuck

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Because of the snapping in Windows (search for "multitasking" in settings), when you move a window from one monitor to another, you need to drag it fast, otherwise it will try to maximize the window (but only fill half the screen).

Is there a way to disable this between monitors completely, but still keep the snapping part for the sides without another monitor?

Example:

```
MONITOR 1|MONITOR 2|MONITOR 3
```

Behavior I want: When I move the window between `MONITOR 2` and `MONITOR 1`, it should move freely (like if snapping was disabled). But when I try to move the window from `MONITOR 2` to the free space above, it should simply maximize the window (just as it does normally).

Answer (score 1):

This is very late but for Windows 10, if you leave snap windows on with the Timeline (Show Suggestions In Your Timeline) setting off, it will still snap at the edges and top, but not between Windows.

Comment: That's it! This seems like a bug; there's no logical relationship between "show suggestions in your timeline" and snapping to screen edges.

Comment: Testing this solution I set Snap to on, Timeline to off. I drag windows and it still snaps between monitors. This answer appears to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Right click on desktop -> Display Settings -> Multi-tasking -> and turn off the top slider (should say something with snap).

Otherwise you can find details here:

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-disable-snap-assist-windows-10/

Comment: I do not have that setting. I have Cortana and so on disabled.

Comment: He said that the snap settings in multi-tasking are what are causing the issue, but he wants to keep snap enabled for screen edges that aren't adjacent to another monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be caused by Windows 10's implementation of Aero Snap. Personally, I disable Aero Snap and then use [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) for snapping instead (which provides a Linux Mint style of window dragging).

#### Disabling Aero Snap

Find setting in start menu:

[image]

Disable window snapping:

[image]

#### Installing a replacement

I still want snapping, just not the default that Windows 10 provides. So I use [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/), which has various snapping options. You may either just enable border snapping, or hold Alt and then drag to the side to snap the window:

[image]

As a somewhat unrelated note, AltDrag currently only works correctly on 100% dpi - there are [forks](https://github.com/RamonUnch/AltDrag) which continue the original work, I'm unsure if this addresses the DPI issues.

Tested on Windows 10 Pro 1909.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my issue in this post below. Essentially the answer lies in how fast Windows is measuring the update speed of the mouse (polling speed). If this is set too high, Windows will detect the mouse approaching the border of the monitor and activate the 'Snap' feature:

https://superuser.com/a/1752978

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate of the other one, you can flag one of them as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Hit the Windows key, type "multi" and you should see a shortcut for "Multitasking Settings".  Click that, disable any/all features you want, it is under "Snap" settings.  Hit the top one to turn them all off.

Comment: That isn't what OP requested. They specifically noted they WANT snapping to work on the outside edges of the screens, and only want it disabled for the between-screen borders. Please read questions carefully and make sure your answers are correct, or else explain how the desired outcome is impossible or inadvisable before "answering" with someone different than requested.