# Cursor cannot move across monitors slowly

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors. If I move my cursor slowly, the cursor cannot cross monitors. It will be stuck to the border of the current monitor.

If I throw my cursor fast enough, it can successfully move across to the other monitor.

I suspect it's a Windows "feature" because I installed updates recently.

My Windows 10 is version 2004.

Can anyone shed light on how to turn the damn feature off?

Comment: Are you perhaps in a corner of the screen?

Comment: @DanielB in the middle. but does it matter?

Comment: I think this is a new feature from a recent Windows update, because it's never happened to me before today. It's driving me nuts, but I can't figure out how to turn it off.

Comment: Hmm, apparently this issue has [existed since 2015](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-mouse-cursor-sticks-to-edge-between/d7480fb3-1d4b-4c3b-9f49-92a75ac45047), but I've never encountered it before today. On the other hand, my update history doesn't show any Windows Updates in the past few days, so there's no reason it would randomly change today...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving windows between monitors makes mouse go stuck](https://superuser.com/questions/1077760/moving-windows-between-monitors-makes-mouse-go-stuck)

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1077760/moving-windows-between-monitors-makes-mouse-go-stuck . Jhonny had the correct answer: you have to turn off "Show suggestions in your timeline", which makes no sense and must be a bug.