# Perfectly arranged monitors won't allow me to move cursor to other monitor, unless I'm going super fast

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a weird issue where I cannot move the cursor from one of my screens to another, unless I literally move the mouse as fast as I can, and even then, it only works once in a while. Here is how an ideal setup looks like:

[image]

And here is how I have to arrange them, to fix this issue:

[image]

However, as you can see, this makes everything shift a bit, which obviously isn't perfect.

What happens in the first picture is, that when I move my cursor between 3 and 4, it's like Windows won't detect it's happening, unless I go super freaking fast. I have tried turning the snap features on and off in the Windows 10 settings, but both result the same.

Also, a funny thing I noticed. There is a gap between the left and right section, but not between the top and bottom sections. Not sure if that's just Windows being Windows, though.

Comment: Does this occur when dragging a window or all the time?  If it's the former, refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1120184/608405).

Comment: @Arctiic Always happening