# How to disable sticky multi-monitor borders in Windows 10 (Fix)

Tags: windows-10

When moving a window from one monitor to another in Windows 10, the mouse will get stuck at the monitor border. This can be overcome when moving the mouse faster. It would be nice to disable this behavior, while retaining other snap features.

This appears to be a similar issue reported [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949749/why-am-i-blocked-from-dragging-windows-across-screen-boundaries-multiple-monito/1120184?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C12.6754#1120184). Current responses seem to focus on understanding and accepting the "feature". This is not the same issue as [sticky corners](https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10).

General suggestions include disabling snap completely, under:

- ControlPanel/System/Multitasking/Snap winddows:off

This does work, but it also removes the ability to use the snap hotkeys (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>, which I would like to retain.

- Set the value HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUi\MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed

This registry setting did not remove the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: I think this is not a copy of the related question: The other question ask "why", not how to disable. I vote to re-open

Comment: When it comes to being a duplicate the actual question isn’t all that important only the answer. If the authors question wasn’t answered by one of those 7 answers to the duplicate then the question should be modified to make that clear. Why and How are oftentimes answered by the same answer

Answer (score 5):

With more research I found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/neep-help-to-disable-aero-snap-between-monitors/c55bb627-9d5b-4751-97cc-812fd1c69059?auth=1&page=2) post by Matt Breedlove. Deep in windows's [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) he discovered a reference to DockTargetMouseWidth, which when set as shown below, does fix this behavior.

It can be added via command line, as show belown, or via registry edit program (win+r: regedit)

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v DockTargetMouseWidth /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

With this registry entry set, the border of monitors no longer stick and the shortcut win+arrow_key continues to work for shortkey window snapping. It would be great if Microsoft added an option to disable this feature, as they've done for snap settings.

[Multitasking Snap Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hEno.png)

Comment: Does this disable snapping between monitors? or snapping entirely for all edges?

Comment: It disable the snapping of the mouse between monitors.

Comment: This does disable window snapping with the mouse.

Comment: Does not work anymore. Window still sticks when moving mouse between monitors. But it appears I set this value to zero in the past, suddenly stopped working today.