# Two monitors: pointer sometimes gets slightly stuck on the edge on one monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse

Recently switched from one to two monitor setup in Windows 10. Sometimes, pointer gets stuck on the edge of one monitor (always the same) and I need to really insist by making huge moves to make the pointer finally cross over to the other monitor.

The weird thing is it seems to happen randomly, most of the time it doesn't occur.

Any idea?

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: I use Windows 10 Pro

Comment: what's the resolution of the monitors and how are they aligned in the window setting (the one I refer to in my answer)?

Comment: This happens when dragging windows because of the sticky window feature.

Comment: This question has not received enough attention. ; )  A comment from @drake035 would be nice before deadline runs out...

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10

Comment: Update your device driver for you display adapter.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10, which talks about the corner of the screens.  This problem is solved by @Emre-Guldogan's answer below (https://superuser.com/a/1526277/48426) which describes a *gap* between the screens on the Display Settings applet.

Answer (score 19):

Depending on the arrangement of the two monitors in your monitor settings - how exactly they align with each other - you might have to move your pointer up or down in order to get to the other monitor. Especially if the two monitors don't have the same resolution, although it can be the case with the same resolution as well.

Here is an example of a two-monitor setting under Windows 10. If you are on the lower right corner of screen 1 (anywhere in the red area) you won't be able to move to the second screen. You will have to move the mouse pointer further up - out of the red area - in order to move to the 2nd monitor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue I'm afraid. Right now, when I move the pointer from one monitor to the other, indeed there's a 10cm vertical jump occuring (left monitor is horizontal, left vertical). That's not a problem for me and that's not my question. My problem is that occasionally, the pointer literally STAYS STUCK along the edge of my vertical monitor and I have to make huge moves so that finally it passes to the other monitor. As I said, it occurs sporadically only.

Comment: @drake035 as I already commented on your're answer, we need to make sure what the resolution and the alignment in you're advanced display settings are. Would be nice if you could either describe it or post a screen shot.

Comment: @drake035 Albin does have a good point, and your description of the vertical jump makes it seem like there is some setting that is a bit off. Whether it's the resolution or the monitor 1, monitor 2 that is in the screenshot. I sometimes encounter the same behavior, but only when dragging a window from one monitor to the next.

Comment: I spent whole day scratching my head over day. Why can't Windows approximate the location and move the cursor to the nearest possible pixel? I don't think anyone would expect the mouse cursor to be on the exact spot. This is not intuitive at all.

Comment: This is NOT solution. This problem is solved by @Emre-Guldogan's answer below (superuser.com/a/1526277/48426) which describes a gap between the screens on the Display Settings applet.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer Please read the comments, Drake already said that this is not the issue for his problem, but it's a helpful solution in many other cases! There might be different solutions for the same symptoms or even the same problem, that's the reason why it is possible to give more than one answer to a question.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer Of course you are free to downvote it, but I would appreciate some constructive criticism on how to improve it. After all, we are all here to help each other and should support us.

Comment: @Albin, I down voted it because it didn't answer the question asked.  It is a perfectly great answer to a different question.  Additionally, since your "answer" has the highest vote, if a person comes here hoping to find the answer to their question, they might not notice the applicable answer to their question.  This was *exactly* the situation *I* was in.  You should move your great answer to an applicable question.

All that said, am I missing something?  Is your answer valid to this question and I'm being thick-headed?  If so, explain and I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer Your statement that this is not the solution might apply to you but not necessarily to other users: As long as a question describes symptoms and not the cause (which is often the case) multiple answers are valid depending on the actual underlying problem as there might be different problems for the same symptoms. It doesn't mean that they should be moved to a different question, on the contrary, they do help a lot of users who have this very question.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer On a personal note, I think, there is no need to artificially downvote questions, it will sort itself out by the community upvoting the answer that solves the problem in the majority of the cases described by the symptoms in the question (sometimes this might even differ from the accepted answer). I do downvote as well, but usually only on answers that need to be improved (and I always leave a comment on how to improve them). But of course, the final choice is yours, but I hope you make it with the common goal in mind.

Comment: @Albin, my only goal is to help users with problems find solutions.  I'm completely confused about your "personal note" comment above.  I didn't downvote the question.  I down voted *your* answer because it *ANSWERED* a different question.  The important point of the question is "I need to really insist by making huge moves to make the pointer finally cross over to the other monitor."  Your answer solves the problem where it is *IMPOSSIBLE* to move the mouse from one screen to the next.  Regardless, this should be moved to meta.  I'll remove my downvote, but sadly SO won't let me.  :-(

Comment: @RandyStegbauer No, it's not the answer to a different question. You have to differentiate between "visible" issues and the "invisible" underlying problems. The issues described in the question can and do originate from different problems therefore requiring different answers. Apparently, the problem I associate with the symptoms seems to resonate with a lot of other users (including myself, I had the same question and the solution I described in my answer solved my particular problem).

Comment: @Albin, we will clearly never agree.  I un-down-voted your answer to another question.  The actual and best answer is the one just below (with nine upvotes right now), which is why I up-voted it.  And all for a five year old question.  I must be bored.  Peace to you.

Answer (score 13):

Let me write my trouble; I've got three screens 1-2 horizontally and 3rd is vertical to them. My trouble is my pointer can access from 1-3 and 2-3 easily, but horizontal 1-2 edge there was a rigid line at the edge so that you **must accelerate** pointer to be able to pass to 1-2 edge. Finally I realized to do that there was **a thick gap** between 1-2 in the plan at the monitor arrangements at the display setting area. And I tried to make them closer at that screen and re-apply the arrangement and my problem, 1-2 hard edge behavior has been disappeared!

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Everything on google for people who has obviously never used multiple monitors before.  I can't believe Windows actually lets you do this, but I'm glad it's such a simple fix!

Comment: +Note: You can set windows separately or seamless. And you can use some windows events on borders in a more relax way in a separate definition (e.g. you can more easily see that a window covers half of the screen at the borders without need for fine mouse movements).

Answer (score 11):

It's not random, nor is it a display alignment issue. It's actually a 'feature' of Windows 10.

<sub>Note: If you want to be able to see for yourself that it is or isn't a display alignment issue, try moving your mouse at an angle so that the cursor 'rubs' against the edge of the display area as it crosses from one monitor to the other, then try doing the same thing again, but going from the second monitor back to the first. If it works in one direction but not the other, it's imperfect alignment, if both directions stop at the corner, it's due to this new feature in Windows.</sub>

I'm not sure what the technical name of this feature is, nor do I know if it was added in Windows 8, 8.1 or 10, but I do know it's not present in Windows 7, and it is present in Windows 10.

The feature I'm referring to is the fact that on Windows 10 moving your cursor from one physical monitor to another will be prevented if the cursor is close enough to the edge of the display area that it thinks you might actually be aiming for the corner of that monitor, instead of trying to get your cursor onto the other monitor. In my experience the threshold appears to be about 5 or so pixels.

I'm unaware of a way to disable this feature (if someone does know of a way, please post some info), however once you're aware of what's actually happening, it's fairly easy to simply move your cursor a little further from the edge of the screen to get around this virtual 'bump'.

Personally, at this point in my Multi-Monitor Windows 10 usage, I'm unsure if I like or dislike this feature, but it would be nice to have the option to disable it if desired.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't noticed this so far, does it work for "every corner"? Just to clarify, what do you mean by working area? The desktop excluding the taskbar or excluding docked windows/toolbars as well?

Comment: @Albin: Sorry, I actually used the wrong term. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I actually meant the display area, by which I mean the area displayed on a monitor. If my settings look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3JLB.png & my desktop background is white & I stick some windows over the edges of my monitors you can see what is/isn't part of the display area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MIvr.png.

Comment: This feature gets triggered on corners of a monitor where one edge of the monitor is also the edge of the display area. So if I adjust my settings so the bottoms of the two monitors line up... the red arrows in this image show where this feature gets triggered, the red line shows an edge where your cursor will stop because there's nowhere for it to go, and the green arrow shows that if you slide your cursor downward along the red edge, this feature won't trigger there, since it's not the corner of the monitor you're leaving: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3nzy.png

Comment: Note: If I had 4 monitors in a 2x2 grid pattern, with the center corners together, these corners would not trigger this feature as they aren't at the edge of the display area, but the corners around the outside edges would.

Comment: interesting which multi monitor mode do you use? in you're screenshot it looks like you use duplicate mode?!

Comment: No. "Duplicate" mode shows the same thing on each monitor. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n54OJ.png ... Those images were of "Extend" mode with one monitor moved 'up' in comparison to the other so that they're offset a bit but still effectively side by side. This matches the physical layout of my monitors so that windows that dragging between them is more natural, and windows don't look broken when they cross the border. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikeTc.jpg

Comment: I've had this problem as well.  I have three monitors.  Laptop #1 (is SurfacePro), 2nd Monitor is above laptop, and 3rd monitor is to the right of the 2nd monitor.  Movement from #1 to #2 is without a problem (no stickyness when moving cursor between #1 to #2, or #2 to #1), but when moving from #2 to #3, the cursor is sticky and won't move to the other monitor until I've moved cursor at a "fast rate".  It is quite annoying.

Comment: This has been an bug with Windows 10 for 5 years now. There is a big thread on Microsoft's site that goes on for 121 pages of comments. I only experience this when I'm in a VM. Someone mentioned it to be a 28 pixel black hole that your mouse cursor gets stuck in. I'm shocked that Microsoft hasn't done anything to fix this.

Comment: This is NOT solution. This problem is solved by @Emre-Guldogan's answer below (superuser.com/a/1526277/48426) which describes a gap between the screens on the Display Settings applet.

Comment: It depends, I arrived at this question and the issue I was having was actually the corner trapping behaviour described in this answer, not a gap solvable by going to display settings. Although I agree that this is technically not a solution because there is apparently no solution to this (very annoying) corner trapping behaviour when moving between monitors.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I figured it out.  I have a Mac.  In System Preferences, Display: when setting the arrangement of the 2 monitors, make sure that the borders of the monitors are touching each other.  That should fix the issue.  If there is a gap, then you will have issue.

Comment: I have a Windows10 machine and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature:
If there is a gap between monitors as Windows sees them you have to "jump" over this.
[monitors position example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz1U1.png)
In this setup the mous moves smoothly in the area where monitors 2 and 3 "touch", as well as between monitors 1 and 3.
The gap between monitors 1 and 2 needs speed to overcome.

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely to be random.

In any multi-monitor setup, what you see & what the computer sees are two different things.

<sup>Pics from a 3-monitor setup, but the same rules apply</sup>

What you see is 2 [or 3] monitors of the same size - you don't really care about the resolution of each.

[image]

What the computer sees, however, is only the resolution of each - it cannot see their physical size. So if they have different resolutions, the computer considers them to be different sizes & you cannot pass from one to the other where there is no screen.

[image]

So to move your cursor from one to another, you need to leave one monitor in an area where the next monitor **exists to the computer**, not your eyes.

Some operating systems will allow you to change the precise area where they meet, so you could for instance set the tops in line, rather than the centres.

Comment: Thanks but most of the time, the transition from one screen to the other is perfectly smooth and normal. The "stuck" issue only occurs sporadically, there I don't think it's related to the things you are pointing out in your answer...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I use the Software **DisplayFusion**, 
it has the Feature **Prevent mouse cursor from snagging on unaligned monitor edges**, search for it in the help: https://www.displayfusion.com/Help/?Version=9.3.99.103#settings-mousemanagement

It's sad that the free edition does not offer this function, search for *Prevent mouse from snagging on unaligned screen edges*:
https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/

But DisplayFusion is very useful and they maintain the Software, so I've got many new features and functions since I bought the license :-)

Comment: It hasen't been verified that non-alignment is the problem. In fact so far it seem it's not.

Comment: If this kind of problem is not caused by an offset (maybe just a few pixels), then we would have a lot employees with the same issue at work. Therefore, I bet that the trial Edition of DisplayFusion will solve the issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem and went into 'Display settings' and rearranged the screens.
After clicking 'Apply' the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 2 different monitors. In screen settings (right click on desktop, and option at the end), drag your monitor 2 a little bit up. Now you can slide with mouse on the bottom side. It feels natural (and more often) to slide using bottom side, than using upper side.

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cLs1.png)

[After I dragged it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu7hQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known windows bug, has been around since 2015.
There's a third party app written to counter this without disabling the snap-to.
Please locate it here https://jawfin.net/nsm

Comment: Interesting! I'd also believe it's a known Windows bug, but do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It's _known_ in that there are multiple threads on answers.microsoft which have gone unheeded (and locked when not solved).  So it is well known - it just is not acknowledged.
Note this unresolved yet locked thread here from 2015 with *21 pages* https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-mouse-cursor-sticks-to-edge-between/d7480fb3-1d4b-4c3b-9f49-92a75ac45047
(Sorry for delay in reply, have been out of town!)

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan

Answer (score -1):

OK, I had this same exact issue. It's like there was an invisible barrier between the monitors that the mouse would not cross unless I moved the cursor to the far side of the monitor and "slammed" the cursor thru the barrier. I fixed it In display settings make sure you have the monitor 1 on the actual side that monitor 1 is physically located in your set up and the same for monitor 2. That seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I have had a similar issue and found that by updating my device driver for my nvidia adapter, the issue was resolved.