# Positions of multiple displays in Windows 10 - control panel doesn't allow fine adjustment

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I use four displays at work.  The windows 10 display control panel allows the user to "select and rearrange displays" but it does not offer fine-grained control over where those displays are positioned.

How display areas touch at, say, a corner, determines whether it is possible to move the mouse easily between them or whether the corner creates a 'trap' that the pointer can get stuck in.

Is there a solution to the problem that the display control panel likes to 'snap' the position of some of the displays into one that is not useful for me?  I try to correct the problem but the display position far "overshoots" where I need it to be.  I need something in the middle of the two positions that the control panel allows.

In the image you see below, it is hard to tell but a 'trap' was created in the lower-right of display 3, such that the pointer cannot travel from the corner of display 3 into display 1.  The control panel does not allow me to line up the right edge of display 3 with the right edge of display 1.  The pointer DOES travel from other areas of display 3 into display 1.

[image: trap was created]

I realize not everyone is going to have my 'problems', please let's keep this discussion to what software does and does not do.

Edit, to those suggesting nvidia/AMD software
The computer does not have an Nvidia or AMD graphics card.  Does that software get the job done regardless of this fact? :)

Comment: Can you use the Nvidia and/or AMD Control Panel software instead?

Comment: Will it let you snap 3 to that edge of 1 if 2 is right out of the way, or does it never snap?

Comment: Re your edit - no, if you don't have dual graphics with NVidia/AMD, then those options are simply not available to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable sticky corners in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10)

Comment: Sure, it's a duplicate, if you already know what sticky corners is and have the knowledge that sticky corners is what is happening.....  Guess what I didn't search for when I experienced this problem.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the snapping when aligning multiple monitors in Windows 10, hold down CTRL while positioning the monitors in settings.

I discovered the solution to this issue while experimenting. Since I couldn't find it via a simple internet search, I figured I'd note a solution for anyone else struggling to resolve this, as this post is the first search result.

Comment: Looks like Shift+Arrow keys does a fine increment of the move on Windows 11

Comment: It still seems to snap once you release the mouse button.

Comment: Both this answer and the first comment should be considered as the whole answer. It does not seem to snap on mouse release with ctrl hold, it recenters the whole setup instead, the delta is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, and finally after quite a long search found a freeware tool that allows a pixel-precise fine tune placement of multi-monitor setup in Windows 10.

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

Comment: What's the "correct" way to move monitors with this tool? I've only been able to do it through File > Save Monitors Configuration > Edit the .cfg in notepad > Load Monitors Configuration, and repeat the last 2 steps until the pixels line up.

Comment: This tool seems to be more for inspection, not editing. Editing is really cumbersome.

Comment: You can edit the positions of the screens by saving the configuration, editing the file and reloading the changed version.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is actually not display arrangement but rather "sticky corners" that cannot be disabled!  However some people have made software to try to address this

[How to disable sticky corners in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947817/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

To make fine-grained monitor position adjustments when aligning multiple monitors in Windows 10 settings, hold down CTRL while adjusting the monitors' relative positions. (This will override the snapping to an invisible grid, that is the default behavior.)

I discovered the solution to this issue while experimenting. Since I couldn't find a solution via a simple internet search, I figured I'd note a solution here for anyone else struggling to resolve this since this question was the first hit in search results