# Mouse gets stuck on edges of different resolution monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, mouse, resolution

I have a high resolution monitor next to a low resolution monitor and when I try to move my mouse from the hi-res one to the low-res one it often sticks on the top or bottom. I understand why this occurs, but I don't understand why the mouse couldn't just wrap to the nearest pixel.

[image]

I tried to find an application that would do this but I've had no luck, does such an application exist? Otherwise what MS documentation one would want to look at to develop such an app?

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/865469/how-to-make-the-mouse-wrap-from-corners-when-moving-between-monitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 11 now has rudimentary support for this built in on the System > Display dialog: "Ease cursor movement between displays".

[image: System > Display]

Answer (score 4):

DisplayFusion will do what you're looking for. https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/MouseManagement/

---

As for why Windows doesn't do this, I actually find the opposite behavior to be most useful.
[image: Diagram of monitor arrangement]

I use the tiny edge at the top-right of monitor 1 to catch my mouse when I want to click the Close Window button.

Ideally, Microsoft would make an option for either, but until then, at least there's DisplayFusion.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks! The option is under the "mouse management" tab for anyone looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

[Continuous Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425) will also do what you are looking for.

I programmed it for the sole purpose to customize the transition between two monitors of different resolution.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425

---

With Continuous Mouse you can also leave out e.G. the upper area to make it easier to reach the close button.

Here is an example configuration:
[image: Example Configuration. in the background is Continuous Mouse]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1123555)

Comment: I adapt my answerer according to the existing answers. Sadly, even in 2022 Windows doesn't provide a build in solution for the purpose, and therefore I need to reference an app that fixes the issue.

Comment: The benefit of Continuous Mouse is that it allows custom transition like in the GIF and also transitions between multiple monitors on one side.